# Using shell (bash) to determine key for value from file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, regex

I am scripting some application deployment and deploy promotion processes using bash (shell). These scripts are being written as a failsafe in case our CI platform ever fails again (as it has recently).

In this process each application has a text file with key value pairs where the key is the name of the deployment region (dev, qa, prod)… and the value is a hash associated with the deployable file(s).

I am struggling to determine how to best approach recognizing the key instead of gathering the value from just sourcing the file in… but sourcing the file in and then manually comparing values for each deployment region seems like it has to be the long way round.

RECAP
 1. I have the value (sha1sum), but I need the key(s) it belongs to
 2. Determine key in key value pair from file
 3. Determine the highest deployment region with the associated value (ie: multiple regions could potentially have the same value listed, the likelihood increases as we climb the chain.)

Any suggestions?

**EDIT 1**
Here is where the needed code would live:

```
###################################################################################################
# IS THIS HASH CURRENTLY DEPLOYED SOMEWHERE ELSE? IF SO, WHERE?
###################################################################################################
grep "${deployHash}" "${deployHashHome}/${deployAppName}/${deployAppName}.manifest"
if [[ "$?" -eq 0 ]]
then
    source ${deployHashHome}/${deployAppName}/${deployAppName}.manifest


    previousDeployRegion=""
    # logThis is a custom logging function which formats logs exactly how we want, we have a Splunk parser for the format
    logThis "${scriptLogDir}/${deployLogFile}" "The hash: ${deployHash}, has been previously deployed to ${previousDeployRegion}." "INFO"
fi
```

Here is what the key-value file looks like:

```
mylocal=ca9c244aa1b40f39fd06318f2be9fbc1a82c5c5c
dev=986b747d846555f8c5e393a5cfbbd061ee9d68a7
int=53b8fa87f2241a17623ead2f94032b1d2045069e
reg=53b8fa87f2241a17623ead2f94032b1d2045069e
stage=
prod=
dr=
```

**EDIT 2**
Added extra example sha1sum values to the example key-value file to show how the same value may exist for multiple keys.

Comment: I guess I understand but some sample would be a good starter.  Probably it's another one for awk.

Comment: Thanks. I added an example of where the code would live, and an example of the file where I need to find the key for a value I already have.

Comment: Oh, the input sample is here as well... yes, I expected this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I would have liked to see some example of the file to work on but the code itself strengthened my assumption.

```
hash="blablabla"
awk -F' *= *' -v hash="$hash" '$2 == hash { print $1 }' your.manifest | sort ...
```

Here we just pass the hash to awk and ask it to split the lines at equal signs. If the value following the sign is the hash, we print out the value before the sign, hopefully the region.
Then you may or may not sort those values according your needs.

If we want to see all keys for a hash, we can use this:

```
awk -F' *= *' -v hash="$hash" '$2 == hash { keys=(keys ? keys "," $1 : $1)}; END { print keys}' your.manifest
```

If only the last key for a hash in the file is interesting, then this code wins:

```
awk -F' *= *' -v hash="$hash" '$2 == hash { key=$1}; END { print key}' your.manifest
```

Comment: Here is how I've attempted your solution, but it appears inoperable for me.

previousDeployRegion=`awk -F'*=*' -v hash=$deployHash '$2 == hash { echo $1 }' $tfDeployHashHome/$deployAppName/$deployAppName.manifest`


logThis "${tfAdminLogDir}/${tfDeployLogFile}" "The hash: ${deployHash}, has been previously deployed to ${previousDeployRegion}." "INFO"


Here is the output:

2016-02-13 19:26:35-05:00 : INFO : The hash: 53b8fa87f2241a17623ead2f94032b1d2045069e, has been previously deployed to .

Suggestions?

Comment: Just throw away your entire script for a moment, and use only what a wrote and you'll see how it works. Of course, replacing blablabla and your.manifest with the real data is a must.

Comment: nvm, I had changed `' *= *'` to `'*=*'` which broke awk. I fixed that change it it now collects the key from the key-value pair! THANK YOU! Now to add support for grabbing only the last key with a matching value!

Comment: Good to hear that.
If you are sure that the last key in order is the one you want to find, just drop one more line, and I'll put that part in the code as well.

Comment: What I am seeking is support for the possibility that the same value may exist for multiple keys.

For example, say code was deployed to DEV, promoted to both INT and REG, and a new build was placed only in DEV. At this point, INT and REG have the same value, but DEV does not. And If I "promoting" the build to the next environment "up" then it would surmise I should push it to STAGE. Yes? I will update the example of the manifest in the OP.

Comment: OK, so two code options added to the answer, just use whichever fits better.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much for your help!